# Not able to delete files from filesystem using php

Tags: php, filesystems, delete-file, unlink

I am not able to delete the files from a folder using php whenever the user clicks yes to delete form submission. 
The files are still present in the folder even after using `unlink()` function:

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='del' value='Yes'>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['del']))
    {

     $filename=$userid.".jpg";
     unlink('upload-cover/uploads/$userid/$filename');
     echo "Your image has been deleted successfully!!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Learn basic PHP syntax: variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the string passed to the unlink function in double-quotes. This is because PHP will interpret strings in single-quotes literally, therefore not including your variables. Try this:

```
unlink("upload-cover/uploads/$userid/$filename");
```

Or:

```
unlink("upload-cover/uploads/".$userid."/".$filename);
```

I think the second option is a lot more readable, and prevents errors like the one you encountered!

This is a great answer to understand PHP strings and paths:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If you use single quotes, the file name genrated will be incorrect.

Also, make sure you have right permissions

Try with

```
 unlink("upload-cover/uploads/$userid/$filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your code it seems that it is variable look up problem

variable inside **single quotes are string** to the php engine

```
unlink('upload-cover/uploads/$userid/$filename');
```

where as variable inside **double quotes are variable** to the php engine

```
unlink("upload-cover/uploads/$userid/$filename");
```